# Topology of $3$-dimensional noncompact Alexandrov space with sec $\ge 0$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, alexandrov-geometry

For any noncompact $3$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$ with sec $\ge 0$, it follows from soul's theorem that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3, S^2 \times \mathbb R$ or their quotients. Can we have a similar topological conclusion for $3$-dimensional noncompact Alexandrov space with sec $\ge 0$?

Comment: See section 17 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0323.pdf.

Comment: Plenty for you here as well: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.1863.pdf